# Browser based terminals

Tags: terminal

Are there any browser based terminals out there? (what are the best ones?)

This would be so someone could access an SSH-style connection without an SSH client. Just a browser. The webserver could be configured with a special filter that only lets in users who have logged in even get to this browser-based terminal.

I am hoping it won't go through the SSH layer but connect directly to the terminal like gnome-terminal does or like the console or SSH server does.

I hope to eventually take all the server interactions to browser-based solutions. The biggest part is Terminal and the second biggest is file transfer but that is easy. Even I could write something up for that and it would be high-pro.

Comment: [The best one is the XKCD one!](http://uni.xkcd.com/) For a certain definition of best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Ajaxterm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/) from time to time and it's about the closest thing I've seen to what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to do.

If you have access to a given server and want to administer that server itself, then sure. I'd recommend [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/):

> Webmin is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix. Using any modern web browser, you can setup user accounts, Apache, DNS, file sharing and much more. Webmin removes the need to manually edit Unix configuration files like /etc/passwd, and lets you manage a system from the console or remotely.

If you want a browser-based tool that lets you connect to *other* servers, then you'll pretty much have to go through ssh. There's [FireSSH](http://lifehacker.com/5783594/firessh-is-a-browser-based-ssh-client-written-entirely-in-javascript) for local-ish use (a Firefox plugin), and several other [hosted and packaged solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH) available.

Comment: I am looking to install something on to the servers I want to connect to so I do not have to install anything on the PC and so I can integrate with the webserver.

Comment: He's trying to *intentionally use* console/ssh access, not avoid it.

Comment: Webmin would be something you'd install on a given server, which you could then connect to from any web browser to administer that server. You don't need any local client software. It includes a plugin that lets you open a terminal session on that server (as well as a plugin for managing and copying files). If that's not what you're looking for, I apologize for the off-topic answer.

Comment: I think that it might be overkill, but since it includes a terminal access plugin browser-based, I will offset the downvote.

Comment: Can you link directly to info on the plugin for the terminal. The big thing is the terminal. GUIs are nice, but they only replace small parts of the terminal and I would like to see more on it.

Comment: [Here is a screenshot and some documentation about the command shell module](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/CommandShell#The_Command_Shell_module). I'm sorry, it does appear to need ssh or telnet access (i.e., it's not a direct pty).